# bash sort characters before numbers

Tags: bash, sorting

How to call sort to ensure that the following list is the result of any its randomizations? In particular, standard sort sorts [0-9] before [A-Za-z] but I need [A-Za-z] before [0-9]. I read the manpage but nothing seems to fit. I read that the locale influences the sorting of individual characters but which locale is the right one?

```
    01_abc
    02_abc
    02_01_abc
    02_02_abc
    02_02_01_abc
    02_02_02_abc
    02_02_03_abc
    02_03_abc
    03_abc
    04_abc
```

Comment: There probably won't be a standard locale for that.  You need to clarify your question; is that the desired output or the actual output or the given input or what?

Comment: It is the desired output. For example: the output of "sort" moves "02_abc" behind "02_03_abc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty ugly, but given a file `data` containing the sample data, and a program `shuffle` that randomizes the sequence of the lines in the file, and `sed` and `sort`, you can use:

```
shuffle data |
sed -e 's/[a-z][a-z]*/a:&/g' -e 's/[0-9][0-9]/d:&/g' |
sort |
sed 's/[ad]://g'
```

The first `sed` tags strings of letters with `a:` (for alpha), and strings of digits with `d:` (for digit), where the crucial point is that `a` comes before `d` in any plausible (ascending) sort order.  This means that the data gets sorted with letters before digits.  The second `sed` removes the tags.

Example of the steps:

```
$ shuffle data
02_03_abc
04_abc
02_02_abc
02_02_02_abc
03_abc
02_02_01_abc
02_01_abc
02_abc
02_02_03_abc
01_abc
$ shuffle data | sed -e 's/[a-z][a-z]*/a:&/g' -e 's/[0-9][0-9]/d:&/g'
d:01_a:abc
d:04_a:abc
d:02_d:02_d:02_a:abc
d:02_a:abc
d:03_a:abc
d:02_d:03_a:abc
d:02_d:02_a:abc
d:02_d:02_d:03_a:abc
d:02_d:02_d:01_a:abc
d:02_d:01_a:abc
$ shuffle data | sed -e 's/[a-z][a-z]*/a:&/g' -e 's/[0-9][0-9]/d:&/g' | sort
d:01_a:abc
d:02_a:abc
d:02_d:01_a:abc
d:02_d:02_a:abc
d:02_d:02_d:01_a:abc
d:02_d:02_d:02_a:abc
d:02_d:02_d:03_a:abc
d:02_d:03_a:abc
d:03_a:abc
d:04_a:abc
$ shuffle data | sed -e 's/[a-z][a-z]*/a:&/g' -e 's/[0-9][0-9]/d:&/g' | sort | sed 's/[ad]://g'
01_abc
02_abc
02_01_abc
02_02_abc
02_02_01_abc
02_02_02_abc
02_02_03_abc
02_03_abc
03_abc
04_abc
$
```

It is important to tag the letter sequences before tagging the number sequences. Note that each time it is run (at least for small numbers of runs), `shuffle` produces a different permutation of the data.

This technique – modifying the input so that the key can be sorted — can be applied to other sort operations too.  Sometimes (often, even), it is better to prefix the key data to the unmodified line, separating the parts with, for example, a tab.  This makes it easier to remove the sort key.  For example, if you need to sort dates with alphabetic month names, you may well need to map the month names to numbers.

Comment: Great. Works as expected. By the way "shuffle" can be "sort -R".

Comment: I can only replace `shuffle` (which is a Perl script in my implementation) with `sort -R` if the `sort` on my systems supports `-R`.  The archaic Linux I use (not through choice — I haven't been around to get it updated) is running GNU CoreUtils 5.97, from circa 2008, and that does not support `-R`.  The current version of `sort` on Mac OS X 10.10.5 is the `sort` from GNU CoreUtils 5.93 and does not support it either, funnily enough.